# SharePoint page with SSRS web parts. How can I change the text of action menu?

Tags: web-part, page-layout, reporting-services

SharePoint page contains a SSRS web parts. How can I change the text of action menu?

Something is work fine with ssrs and corrent and rdl file but is it possible to modify the text of action menu?

I tested to update the text with jQuery onload event but it is not working. Web part will get data after page onload.

Is it possible have a event after SSRS web part has loaded the data?

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, I'm modifying the parameter pane like below. So load this on the page where you have the web part. I have it in a JS file referenced by script tag in master page, but other ways will probably work as well.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_beginRequest(function (sender, e) {
        //Event Raised when the Async Postback is starting.
    });

    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        //Event Raised when the Async Postback is completed.    
        //Here the SSRS web part has been loaded and you can do your thing
    });
}
```